# Drag and drop change image with switch

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, switch-statement

i am working on my game but i have some problems...

**1.** if the image is in the class *.room* it has a another src but if you drop it in the class *.items* it should change to a icon. And if you drag it again to *.room* it will turn back.
**2.** There are many different image so i want to have a switch. if the draged objekt is dragging to *.items* the image should change. so the id of the image should go to the switch and check if the id and case is the same. the scr should be from the icon.

**3.** if it is possible i want to safe the id of the image in local.storage so i can use the objekt in the next page

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.room {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.items {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    if (ev.target.className === "items") {
        ev.target.style.border = "3px dashed black";
    }
    ev.preventDefault(); 
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("img", ev.target.id);
}

function dragleave(ev) {
    if (ev.target.className === "items") {
        ev.target.style.border = "0px dashed transparent";
    }
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("img");
    ev.target.style.border = "0px dashed transparent";
    if (ev.target=="[object HTMLImageElement]"){
           ev.target = ev.target.parentNode;
        }
    else { 
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

if (ev.target.id === ev.dataTransfer.getData("ori")) {
  return;
}
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.id = 
    image.draggable = true;
    image.addEventListener('dragstart', drag);
    if (ev.target.className === 'items') {
      icon();
    } else if (ev.target.className === 'room') {
      room();
    }
    var originEle = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("ori"));
    originEle.outerHTML = '';
    delete originEle;
    ev.target.appendChild(image);
}    

function icon(){
    switch(image.id) {
           case "teddy":     image.src="pic/Icons/teddy.png";break;
           case "book":     image.src="pic/Icons/Buch.png";break;
    }
}
function room(){ 
    switch(image.id) {
           case "teddy":     image.src= "pic/Home/HomeRoom_booksL.png";break;
           case "booksR":     image.src= "pic/Home/HomeRoom_buch.png";break;}
}

function reset(){
    var container = document.getElementById("field");
    container.innerHTML= html;
}                
var html;
window.onload = function(){
    html = document.getElementById('field').innerHTML;
};  

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<div>
    <div class="room" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div>
    <h2>items</h2>
    <div class="items" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img id="book" src="pic/Icons/Buch.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">

        <img id="teddy" alt="booksL"src="pic/Home/HomeRoom_teddy.png" id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

About the 3rd question - saving to localStorage:
add the code below to your drop function.

```
localStorage.setItem("name", data);
```

Comment: about your other questions you are trying to change the img src after droping?  can you explain more?